# `change` event doesn't call when `input` changed by programmatic methods

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have this sample code:

```js
//It's my code editable
document.querySelector('#word').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = this.value + "!";
});

//-------------------------

//You should not make any changes to this section of the code below, 
// as it is an instance and may be similar to another program and elsewhere 
// that cannot be identified.
document.querySelector('#fill').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#word').value = "sample text";
});
```

```html
<input id="word">
<button id="fill">Change it!</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

*mirror code: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/t7ps4exj/*

When I change value of `input` element by keyboard or mouse, the event `change` works well.
But when I use of any programmatic method, that does not works.

For example when I click on `button` at this sample code, the values will be changed, But the input `change` event does not call.

**Note:** You suppose that you don't should any change in button event click function, because this button in here is just an example, and maybe the input value will be changed by any way in any time and by any happen!

What's your solution for this problem?

**EDITED:**
**Note 2:** I'm adding a small piece of code as a `Tampermonkey` to a large web app that I can't change in all the code available throughout the program. This program may change the value of this `input` box at any time and in any way and I need to understand it by the `change` event **or any best practices methods.**

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm changing a big program that has lots of functions and I want add a bit code inside here; my event to work immediately when an input changes in any way I don't know.

Comment: You could use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and trigger the change event when the setter is called. But the rest of the program would have to reference the proxy object instead of the DOM object itself when setting value, eg `proxy.value = ...` instead of `dom.value = ...`

Comment: @PatrickEvans as I said in previous comment, I don't can change in previous codes of current program... (I add note2 and add comment in codes in my question)

Comment: Then there is no other native process to detect the change. You would either have to do a frequent polling of input value using like setInterval or since you are using tampermonkey replace the web app script that would be altering the input to a modified one that you would make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I didn't found any way better than monitor the value of `input` for change:

```js
//It's my code editable
var old_word;
setInterval(function() {
  var current_word = document.querySelector('#word').value;
  if (old_word != current_word) {
    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = current_word + "!";
    old_word = current_word;
  }
}, 100);

//-------------------------

//You should not make any changes to this section of the code below, 
// as it is an instance and may be similar to another program and elsewhere 
// that cannot be identified.
document.querySelector('#fill').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#word').value = "sample text";
});
```

```html
<input id="word">
<button id="fill">Change it!</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

*mirror code: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/t7ps4exj/13/*

Answer (score -3):

You can redefine value setter for HTMLInputElememnt

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value', {
  set: function (value) { 
     this.setAttribute('value', value)
     updateHandler();
  }
});
```

Comment: it's not possible. I thinks you didn't read latest NOTE in my question.

Comment: i added another suggestion to my answer, please check

Comment: Yes I know about setInterval and check input, but this way have delay, but don't have any idea  for use change event?!

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z.check another suggestion - redefine property value